# Background Color in CSS Going Over in Table

Tags: html, css, padding, background-color

In my HTML project, I set the background color of a table `tr` to white, but it goes over the edge of the table with `padding = 10px;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>--!</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
.topnav {
  background-color: #11a642;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #0a6127;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #11a642;
  color: white;
}
.topnav a.active:hover {
    background-color: #0a6127;
}
#noCss {
    display: none;
}
#page {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class = "topnav">
    <a href="/home" class="active"><b>--</b></a>
    <a href="/stuff">My Folders</a>
    <a href="/search">Search</a>
    <a href="/home" id="yellow" style="float:right;">Sign up</a>
    <a href="/home" style="float:right;">Log In</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<center>
<div id="noCss" style="background-color: #a7ab35;width: 70%; border: 1px solid black;">
<br>
<h2>⚠️ Uh-oh ⚠️</h2>
It looks like the CSS didn't load. Please reload the page.
<br><br><span style="color:#a7ab35;">.</span>
</div>
</center>

<div id="page">
<h2>--</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div class="box">
    hi
    </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice when you run it the white background sticks out.

[Image of background going over edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOEQO.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: set `max-width: 100%` instead of `width:100%` to  `.box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

You given here `width:100%;padding:10px;` makes

**width = 100% + 20px (both left and right)**

so, one method to using **`calc()`** in CSS to minus 20px padding

```
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); // minus padding of both left and right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>--!</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
.topnav {
  background-color: #11a642;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #0a6127;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #11a642;
  color: white;
}
.topnav a.active:hover {
    background-color: #0a6127;
}
#noCss {
    display: none;
}
#page {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class = "topnav">
    <a href="/home" class="active"><b>--</b></a>
    <a href="/stuff">My Folders</a>
    <a href="/search">Search</a>
    <a href="/home" id="yellow" style="float:right;">Sign up</a>
    <a href="/home" style="float:right;">Log In</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<center>
<div id="noCss" style="background-color: #a7ab35;width: 70%; border: 1px solid black;">
<br>
<h2>⚠️ Uh-oh ⚠️</h2>
It looks like the CSS didn't load. Please reload the page.
<br><br><span style="color:#a7ab35;">.</span>
</div>
</center>

<div id="page">
<h2>--</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div class="box">
    hi
    </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Or**

> no need to assign `width:100%;` actually in here one  having given **width:100%**

so just remove the **`width:100%;`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>--!</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
.topnav {
  background-color: #11a642;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #0a6127;
}
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #11a642;
  color: white;
}
.topnav a.active:hover {
    background-color: #0a6127;
}
#noCss {
    display: none;
}
#page {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class = "topnav">
    <a href="/home" class="active"><b>--</b></a>
    <a href="/stuff">My Folders</a>
    <a href="/search">Search</a>
    <a href="/home" id="yellow" style="float:right;">Sign up</a>
    <a href="/home" style="float:right;">Log In</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<center>
<div id="noCss" style="background-color: #a7ab35;width: 70%; border: 1px solid black;">
<br>
<h2>⚠️ Uh-oh ⚠️</h2>
It looks like the CSS didn't load. Please reload the page.
<br><br><span style="color:#a7ab35;">.</span>
</div>
</center>

<div id="page">
<h2>--</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div class="box">
    hi
    </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```